# Removing Duplicates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to delete duplicates in excel sheet while comparing second column in sheet. I have an excel sheet with two columns A and B, while values repeat in both columns but i only want to remove values in column B which is appearing again against same value of column A. For example:

```
 A    B
ABC  DEF  
ABC  GHI
ABC  DEF
QWE  DEF
QWE  IKI
QWE  DEF
```

---> want to remove DEF duplicate value against ABC and QWE, DEF should appear once against ABC and QWE.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, your post needs some illustration for better understanding!!

Comment: Select the data, then go to the `Data` tab, `Remove Duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

Select 2 Columns- go to Data- Remove Duplicates:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it worked as per my requirement :-)