# Deleting Repeated cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, duplicate, wps-spreadsheet

I am comparing 2 columns in WPS spreadsheet using the 'Highlight Duplicates' option. Once it is highlighted, if I use remove duplicates it isn't deleting the duplicates. If i  manually delete the cells, the highlighted cells, will be de-higlighted.

I want to check for duplicates in these two columns and deleted the duplicated cells, so I can take the remaining cells and remove the required data.

[Image containing the data](https://superuser.com/questions/1425497/removing-duplicates-in-excel)  [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1425497/removing-duplicates-in-excel): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVoGv.jpg

I tried using the result in this link but it doesn't work for me. ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/1425497/removing-duplicates-in-excel))
Is that if there is a function that can check for duplicates in both the columns. (It has to use the value in Column A and check for it completely in Column B and highlight the cell with which it matches.)

Answer (score 0):

**This method will help you to Delete Duplicate Values from multiple Cells:**

[image]

**Step 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select entire data range & Apply **Conditional 
  Format**, write this Formula for **New Rule**.

  `=COUNTIF($A2:$C2,A2)>1`
- Apply an appropriate **Format** & finish with 
  **Ok**.

**Step 2:**

- Copy & Paste this VBA(Macro) Code with the 
  Sheet as Standard Module.

  ```
  Sub DeleteCells()

  Range("A2:C4").Select
  For Each Cells In Selection

      If Cells.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then

  Cells.ClearContents
  Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone

      End If
  Next

  End Sub
  ```
- RUN the Macro.

[image]

**N.B.**

- Adjust cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.
- In VBA code `rgbYellow` is editable.

Comment: I do not have the macro option in WPS spreadsheet. I have a basic version, not a business edition. Is there a work around this?